# Find the external work for getting the wire from $\infty$ to the current location. (the potential in $\infty$ is $0$)

Tags: electricity, electric-current, charge, work

A ball of radius $R$, with charge density:
$$\rho(r)=\beta r,\quad\beta > 0$$

A thin wire, with charge density: $\lambda[\frac{c}{m}]$  and length $R$, located between $x=2R$ and $x=3R$.

[image]

My attempt:

External work :

$$W=\frac{kQ_\text{ball}Q_\text{wire}}{r_A}-\frac{kQ_\text{ball}Q_\text{wire}}{r_B}.$$

$$A=\infty,B=x, \qquad\text{such that}\qquad 2R\leq x\leq 3R.$$

$$Q_\text{ball}=\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}r^2\sin\theta \cdot \beta r   \ dr\;d\phi\; d\theta.$$

Each little piece of the wire with density $\lambda$.

And I have to take each piece from $\infty$ to $x$ such that $2R\leq x\leq 3R$.
$$W=\int _0^{\pi }\:\int _0^{2\pi }\:\int _0^Rk\:r^2\sin\theta\ \beta \lambda \ dr\;d\phi \;d\theta = 65\pi kλβr^4.$$

My answer is wrong, the correct answer is:
$$k\pi\beta R^4 \lambda \ln\!\left(\frac{3}{2}\right).$$

How am I supposed to solve this problem?

Any help is welcome, thanks!